# Python XLWT - Insert Image aligned to top-right corner of cell

Tags: python, image, xlwt

Given an image that is the width of multiple columns, I want to insert it such that it is right aligned to a specific column. I know I can insert an image aligned to the top left corner via the following line:

```
sheet.insert_bitmap(filepath_to_bmp, row, col)
```

I also see that there are four optional values afterwards, `x`, `y`, `scale_x`, and `scale_y`.

If I can't align to the top-right corner, the size of the columns are fixed, and if I could do offsets from the top-left corner, that would answer the question, but only if top-right-corner alignment isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment to the top right corner isn't supported. As a workaround you can offset from the top left. Something like:

```python
x = column_width - image_width

sheet.insert_bitmap(filepath_to_bmp, row, col, x)
```

All dimensions should be in pixels.